# Starting a path on a decoration of another path

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

In the following code, I would like to connect the plus sign to the focusing rectangle containing **2 * 3 + 11 = 17**. I have a connection but it is not the wanted one.

I do not want the small red line crossed off in green, and I would like a line starting from the PLUS sign.

What am I missing ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix}

\tikzset{ope/.style={circle,draw,fill=white,inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt},
block/.style={
  rectangle,
  draw=blue,
  thick,
  fill=blue!20,
  text width=5em,
  align=center,
  rounded corners,
  minimum height=2em},
blur/.style={opacity=0.3},
focus/.style={rectangle,
  thick,
  rounded corners,
  minimum height=2em,
  align=center,
  draw=red,
  text=magenta}}    

\begin{document}

% Source for decorated paths
%    * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507419/6880

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,
    row sep  = 1em,
    column sep = 1.5em
  ](mat){
                &  9665              &              && |[focus]| {$2 \times 3 + 11 = 17$}  \\
    |[block]| 2 &  |[blur]|488888887 & |[block]| 3                                         \\
                &  777               & |[block]| 11                                        \\
                &                    &  99                                                 \\
    };

  \draw[red] (mat-2-1) -- (mat-2-3) node[midway,draw,ope]{$\times$};

  \draw[red] (mat-2-3.east) -- ++ (1,0) -| ++ (0,-.5) coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux) |- (mat-3-3.east);

  \draw[red] (mat-3-3.east) -| (aux) node[pos=0.75,draw,ope]{$+$}  -| (mat-1-5.south);

  \draw[red,-triangle 60] (mat-1-5.west) -- ++ (-1,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `positioning` to position the new node (instead of putting it into the matrix)?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix,positioning}

\tikzset{ope/.style={circle,draw,fill=white,inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt},
block/.style={
  rectangle,
  draw=blue,
  thick,
  fill=blue!20,
  text width=5em,
  align=center,
  rounded corners,
  minimum height=2em},
blur/.style={opacity=0.3},
focus/.style={rectangle,
  thick,
  rounded corners,
  minimum height=2em,
  align=center,
  draw=red,
  text=magenta}}


\begin{document}

% Source for decorated paths
%    * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507419/6880

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,
    row sep  = 1em,
    column sep = 1.5em
  ](mat){
                &  9665              &              \\
    |[block]| 2 &  |[blur]|488888887 & |[block]| 3                                         \\
                &  777               & |[block]| 11                                        \\
                &                    &  99                                                 \\
    };

  \draw[red] (mat-2-1) -- (mat-2-3) node[midway,draw,ope]{$\times$};

  \draw[red] (mat-2-3.east) -- ++ (1,0) |- (mat-3-3.east)
   node[pos=0.25,draw,ope](plus){$+$}
   node[above right=1cm and 1cm of plus,focus] (f){$2 \times 3 + 11 = 17$} ;    
  \draw[red,-triangle 60] (plus) -| (f) (f.west) --  ++(-1,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I would like the + to stay between and connect to 3 and 11. Then I would like a path from + to 2*3+11=37. (I'm very new to TikZ)

Comment: @projetmbc Yes, sorry, there was a typo `|- (mat-2-3.east)` needed to become `|- (mat-3-3.east)`.

Comment: Thanks. I really need to practice TiKz. So cute and no so hard to read.

Comment: @projetmbc You're welcome! Ti*k*Z has become a really large package so it takes time to get used to it but I think on the long run it pays off.